# Issue with Date and TimeZone java

Tags: java, date, timezone

I have a really strange problem about showing dates. And particulary in windows. I dont know why, when i get a Date from a query (Hibernate) it gives me one day less. when the data gets to the server the date is fine but when it gets to the client it gives one day less.  For example: in the server the date is **Fri Sep 24 00:00:00 1982** but when it gets to the client is  **Thu Sep 23 23:00:00 1982**. As you can see its one difference day.

Ah and i almost forget to mention it happens on windows (Seven) as its TimeZone its UTC instead of GMT. Me and my colegues use Linux and there is no problem with it.

Is there any workaround about this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As Jon Skeet said, it is probably time zone related. You may have to check the time zone settings for the various software pieces which touch the date (DB server, JDBC, ...). I was working on a JDBC driver some time ago and took care of those issues. If you want to be sure, check with date and time values especially when DST changes and several hours before and after that. Time zone and DST-change related implementations are surprisingly tricky to get right. In some setups you are doomed by the implementation of software components and won't be able to set up a reliably working system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not giving you a value a *day* earlier. It's giving you a value an *hour* earlier (midnight on September 24th vs 11pm on September 23rd).

That's almost certainly a time zone issue, which is almost certainly just a reflection of how you're formatting your dates. If you use `SimpleDateFormatter`, just set the `TimeZone` appropriately (your actual requirements will determine which zone that is) and you should get the same results.

As an aside, in general I'd recommend using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) as far as possible when it comes to date/time work in Java - it's a much cleaner API than `Date` and `Calendar`.

Comment: the thing is that i dont even set any format. I only print it. It shouldnt have any change right? :\

Comment: @JesusGutierrez: If you mean you're using `Date.toString()`, that always uses the default time zone of your system - but I'd expect it to include that time zone offset in the output. It's not going to be possible to help you further without much more detail about *exactly* how you're examining the values on both systems, and how it's transferred from the server to the client.

Comment: I replaced the Date fields with joda time. At the end i noticed that it only happens with dates before 1983. Its kinda strange. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JesusGutierrez: Well, you still haven't provided any of the details I've asked about, but the "not before 1983" is an interesting point. I suspect this is due to a difference in Windows vs Linux understanding of the UK time zone. I'll look into that.

Comment: i use a SwingX DateTimePicker to show the date. Now that i changed to joda i have no problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

As [Jon Skeet correctly points](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12270853/642706), likely you have a time zone problem. Likely your middleware tools are dynamically applying a default time zone, a well-intentioned but very confusing anti-feature.

The modern solution is to use the *java.time* classes added to Java 8 and later.

As of JDBC 4.2, we can exchange *java.time* objects with the database. Hibernate and JPA have been updated to handle *java.time* as well.

Retrieval from a column of type akin to `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = myResultSet.getObject( … , OffsetDateTime.class ) ;
```

Writing.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , odt ) ;
```

By using these objects, you will avoid your middleware tool from applying a time zone. With JDBC 4.2 retrieving *java.time* objects, you will see the value as it was truly stored.

[image: Table of date-time types in Java (both legacy and modern) and in standard SQL]

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).